# How to load textures in Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I use [ShoeBox](http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/) to make a SpriteSheet. It creates 2 files, *.txt and *.png. How can I load each texture from those files in libgdx?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any information about compatibility of LibGDX and ShoeBox texture atlases. I think it's better to use [TexturePacker](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer) to pack your textures because it's officially supported.